# Temperature sensors for low temperature

Tags: sensor, temperature

I want to find a temperature sensor able to be used from -80 °C to 20 °C, measuring air temperature, with a potentially low pressure, reaching 1 kPa. Another constraint is that it should be as small as possible (a thermistor or TO-92 is small enough, though). Finally, its accuracy should be around 0.5 - 1 °C.

However, all the sensors I've found (mainly thermistors, and chips like the TI LMT87 or Tsic301) are only said to work in temperature above -50 °C.

What sensor could I use ?

Comment: Would something like this work?  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/us-sensor-littelfuse-inc/PPG102A6/615-1123-ND/3103190

Comment: You want to use a thermocouple.

Comment: Use a Thermocouple such as this: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Digilent%20PDFs/240-080_Web.pdf

Comment: Why not use a platinum RTD? I'm not sure a thermocouple can meet the 0.5 - 1 °C accuracy requirement. (Assuming they meant accuracy, not precision)

Comment: @SolveEtCoagula07, yes it is exactly what is needed, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a platinum RTD like the [PPG102A6](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/us-sensor-littelfuse-inc/PPG102A6/615-1123-ND/3103190).  This has a temperature range of -200C to 600C with an accuracy of +/-0.15C

Answer (score 3):

For that temperature range, I would suggest either a type T (Copper-Constantan) thermocouple or a platinum RTD. (100 or 1000 ohms).

Thermocouples are vastly more rugged and usually are much faster response but require signal conditioning (including cold-junction compensation). RTDs are more accurate and (electrically) easier to use.